# Trying to convert binary to decimal: ended with a weird int error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I'm writing a python code that converts a binary to decimal.

```
def bin_dec (binary):
    binary_list = list(str(binary))
    **for bit in binary_list:
        if int(bit) > 1 or int(bit) < 0:
            print('Invalid Binary')
            print('')
            exit()**    
    total = 0
    argument = 0
    binary_length = len(str(binary))
    exponent = binary_length - 1
    while exponent >= 0:
        total += (int(binary_list[argument]) * (2**exponent))
        argument += 1
        exponent -= 1
    print(total)
    print('')
```

When I test the code with neagtive binary numbers I don't see the output "Invalid Binary"
Instead I see an integer error

```
>>> bin_dec(-10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    bin_dec(-10)
  File "E:/Bronx Science/Sophomore/Computer Science_Python/Edwin Chen_Lab 8_Diamond and Squares.py", **line 27, in bin_dec
    if int(bit) > 1 or int(bit) < 0:**
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
```

Comment: If `bit` is the string `'-'`, `int(bit)` will give this error you have seen. Which number did you expect `int('-')` to result in?

Comment: If you want to handle negative numbers, you need to check if the string is `'-'` *before* trying to convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ValueError` is being raised as soon as you say `int(bit)`, because `bit` is `'-'`.  You never get to the next line of your code because the exception isn't caught, so it raises all the way out of your script.

Instead of:

```
for bit in binary_list:
    if int(bit) > 1 or int(bit) < 0:
        print('Invalid Binary')
        exit()
```

you could do something like:

```
for bit in binary_list:
    try:
        assert 0 <= int(bit) <= 1
    except AssertionError, ValueError:
        print('Invalid Binary')
        exit()
```

Note that calling `exit()` in a function is usually considered bad practice.  If you simply allow the exception to raise, it will cause the script to exit anyway, so you can just do:

```
for bit in binary_list:
    assert 0 <= int(bit) <= 1, 'Invalid Binary'
```

or maybe:

```
assert all(bit in {'0', '1'} for bit in binary_list), 'Invalid Binary'
```

and get essentially the same effect (plus a stack trace that will tell the user what exactly killed the script).  The difference with this approach is that if the caller of the function decides they want to do something else (like try prompting the user for another number), they have the option of `catch`ing the exception; if you just `exit()` they have no opportunity to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually here what is happening is when you pass `-10` as input, the contents of `binary_list` now are `['-', '1', '0']`

So, now you when you try to do `int(bit)`, python throws an error as you can't convert `-` to int.

You can do something like this to detect invalid binary numbers

```py
for bit in binary_list:
    if bit != '0' and bit != '1':
        print('Invalid Binary')
        print('')
        exit()
```